# É possível retornar um valor usando RemoteCommand?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2.2

Gostaria de saber se da mesma maneira que é possível passar parâmetros para uma função de um "remoteCommand" se é possível receber o retorno? 
Tal como o exemplo:

Xhtml:`<p:remoteCommand name="myRemoteCommand" actionListener="#{testBean.testRemote }" />`

JavaSctript: `myRemoteCommand([{name:"id", 1}]);`

Bean:

```
public void testRemote()
    {
        String[] id = JSFUtil.getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
        System.out.println(id);     
    }
```

Eu preciso que minha função "testRemote" retorne um valor, e eu captura esse valor após a chamada, como exemplo:

JavaSctript:`alert(myRemoteCommand([{name:"id", 1}]));`

Bean:

```
public String testRemote()
    {
        String[] id = JSFUtil.getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
        System.out.println(id);     
        return “Test Success”;
    }
```

Comment: Leonardo, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Aqui as perguntas devem ser postadas somente em português, clique em [edit] na sua pergunta e a traduza que iremos te ajudar ou, caso queira realmente postar em inglês, você deve ir ao [so].

Answer (score 0):

Bem você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
public String testRemote()
{
    String[] id = JSFUtil.getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
    System.out.println(id); 
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("alert(myRemoteCommand([{name:'id', 1}]));");
    return “Test Success”;
}
```

Dentro do `execute` você pode mandar executar qualquer *JavaScript*. Creio que `remoteCommand` não tenha evento de retorno.